# How to Install Oracle Apex in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, oracle

Can anyone plz Help me to install/ config Oracle apex in my system(Ubuntu) I downloaded ORACLE_APEX and Move it to $ORACLE_HOME Directory

[Click Here To See Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPLRj.png)

N.B: i'm new in Ubuntu. Plz Provide Step by Step Guide